# Center Price on grid, and left on list

Tags: magento2.4

i am creating my own theme by learning by myself and i managed to center the content of the price, name, add to car button by adding this line on

.product-item-details {
text-align: center !important;
}

app/design/frontend/infinity/tema/web/css/source/_extend.less

Well the thing is, when i do this it also center on list mode, and that looks awful, could any point me in the right direction to modify them separately?

Here are the pics.
[image: GOOD]

[image: BAD]

Answer (score 0):

You should use css class with the different parent class for product list page.

Comment: Thanks that solved the question.

Comment: You're most welcome. Please upvote the answer if you may.

Comment: Already did but i think my rep is so low it doesnt record it...